# Translate plugin and wordpress and the same time

Tags: wordpress, translation

I have seen many questions and answers but none that fit the bill. So here is my issue.

I have a plugin that I have localized which works fine on it's own when you add

```
define('WPLANG', 'my-plugin-name-de_DE');
```

to the wp-config file. But then when someone try's to translate the rest of the wp site it will not show the languange.

What am I missing here? I even tried naming the files I added the the wp-content folder to be the same name as my plugin... for example my-plugin-name-de_DE.po and .mo and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER

Ok so in wordpress 4.0 you can now select your language from the settings /general page.

My plugin was localized using the code

```
function plugin_action_init()
 {
 // Localization
  load_plugin_textdomain('my-plugin-name', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
 }
 // Add actions
add_action('init', 'plugin_action_init');
```

Example of a string that would get translated.

```
_e('Simple text example', 'my-plugin-name');
```

**SO** all that needed to be done to get my plugin's and wordpress's translation to work at the same time was to upload the wp language that I want to the wp-content/languages folder. Making sure the file name was simply de_DE.mo and  de_DE.po

Such a simple mistake :)